# usingComparatorForType in assertj does not seem to apply to properties of objects that are properties of the object

Tags: java, assertj

I want to test equality of two objects but have a certain discretion about the precision of `double` values that are present on some nested properties of them. [usingComparatorForType](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-news.html#assertj-core-2.4.0-usingComparatorForType) seems to be an appropriate solution but it doesn't appear to work if my `Foo` object has a propery of type `Bar` where `Bar.baz` is a `double` which I want this precision discretion to apply to. [The example for `isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#field-by-field-recursive) doesn't quite address the situation I'm trying to test.

**Some sample code**

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Objects;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ComparatorForTypeTest {

  private static final Comparator<Double> DOUBLE_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Double>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Double d1, Double d2) {
      return Math.abs(d1 - d2) <= 0.1 ? 0 : 1;
    }
  };

  class Foo {
    private int id;
    private double baz;
    private Bar bar;

    public Foo(int id, double baz, Bar bar) {
      this.id = id;
      this.baz = baz;
      this.bar = bar;
    }

    public Foo withBar(Bar bar) {
      Foo that = this;
      that.bar = bar;
      return that;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      return Objects.hash(id, baz, bar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (this == obj) {
        return true;
      } else if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != Foo.class) {
        return false;
      }

      Foo that = (Foo) obj;
      return Objects.equals(this.id, that.id)
          && Objects.equals(this.baz, that.baz)
          && Objects.equals(this.bar, that.bar);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return String.format("Foo[id=%d, score=%f, bar=%s]", id, baz, bar == null ? null : bar.toString());
    }
  }

  class Bar {
    private int id;
    private double baz;

    public Bar(int id, double baz) {
      this.id = id;
      this.baz = baz;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      return Objects.hash(id, baz);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (this == obj) {
        return true;
      } else if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != Bar.class) {
        return false;
      }

      Bar that = (Bar) obj;
      return Objects.equals(this.id, that.id)
          && Objects.equals(this.baz, that.baz);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return String.format("Bar[id=%d, score=%f]", id, baz);
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void itComparesBars() {
    Bar a = new Bar(1, 1.4);
    Bar b = new Bar(1, 1.45);
    Bar c = new Bar(2, 1.4);

    assertThat(a).isNotEqualTo(b);
    assertThat(b).isNotEqualTo(c);
    assertThat(a).isNotEqualTo(c);

    assertThat(a).usingComparatorForType(DOUBLE_COMPARATOR, Double.class).isEqualToComparingFieldByField(b);
  }

  @Test
  public void itComparesFoos() {
    Foo a = new Foo(1, 1.4, null);
    Foo b = new Foo(1, 1.45, null);
    Foo c = new Foo(2, 1.4, null);

    assertThat(a).isNotEqualTo(b);
    assertThat(b).isNotEqualTo(c);
    assertThat(a).isNotEqualTo(c);

    assertThat(a).usingComparatorForType(DOUBLE_COMPARATOR, Double.class).isEqualToComparingFieldByField(b);

    Bar barA = new Bar(1, 1.4);
    Bar barB = new Bar(1, 1.45);

    assertThat(a.withBar(barA)).usingComparatorForType(DOUBLE_COMPARATOR, Double.class).isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively(b.withBar(barA));
    assertThat(a.withBar(barA)).usingComparatorForType(DOUBLE_COMPARATOR, Double.class).isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively(b.withBar(barB));
  }
}
```

In this case, `itComparesFoos` is where I'm looking to apply this discretion about the precision of doubles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that `Bar` has an overridden `equals` method and this is used to compare `Bar` instances, this is mentioned in the [javadoc](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively-java.lang.Object-) (but I get that javadoc is not always the best way to discover an API):

> The recursive property/field comparison is not applied on fields having a custom equals implementation, i.e. the overridden equals method will be used instead of a field by field comparison.

https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/1002 is a ticket to revamp the recursive comparison api which has gone wild, it will provide an option to force recursive comparison even if `equals` was overridden (likely [`forcingRecursiveComparisonForAll`](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/1002#issuecomment-304657318)).

Comment: Better use the recursive comparison, it will compare objects field by field ignoring any overridden equals by default see -  now https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-recursive-comparison